# Let $f(x),g(x)$ differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and $f(-2)=g(-2)=0$. Find $\lim _{x\to -2}\frac {f(x)g(x)}{x^2-4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f(x),g(x)$ differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and $f(-2)=g(-2)=0$. Find $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to -2}\frac {f(x)g(x)}{x^2-4}$

After applying LHR twice I get $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to -2}f'(x)g'(x)$ but now I'm stuck, any hints please?

Comment: You can apply LHR only once since after applying it you don't have a intermediate form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\lim _{x\to -2}\frac {f(x)g(x)}{x^2-4}=\lim _{x\to -2}\frac {f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)}{2x}=0$$